# Adding gameCenter functionality with actionscript3 and Adobe AIR

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, actionscript-3, air

I am writing a game in actionscript3 and adobe AIR for the iphone4. Is there a way to connect to iphone's gameCenter in actionscript3, or is that not possible and I am forced to use xcode and objective-C?

If this is not possible, are there any alternatives to gameCenter that I can program with actionscript3 and AIR? For example openFeint??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page has a few good tools for AIR to mobile, including a Game Center extension ($70)

http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/

Comment: is there any free extensions I could use. I know 70$ isn't that expensive. Still if there is an option to get it for free, i wouldn't mind.

Comment: that's alright, thanks anyways =). I will keep this question open for another day, if I don't get any more answers I will accept yours =)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's a free github version here:

https://github.com/dflatley/Adobe-Native-Extension-for-iOS-Game-Center

More details on how to use it here: 
http://www.davidflatley.com/2012/02/06/adobe-native-extension-for-ios-game-center-part-1/

Comment: you rock! finally a free version. you should post this everywhere (there's a bunch of threads of people asking for free versions)

Answer (score 2):

Richard Lord also just released this version on git for free

https://github.com/StickSports/ANE-Game-Center